# Hichcharts (Highstock) — Why isn't the plotLine being drawn on the chart?

Tags: highcharts

Why isn't the plotLine being drawn on the chart? I've been trying to figure this out for at least 2 hours.

The goal is to add a plotLine in line with a candlestick at any given index (100 in the example). So candle at index 100 in the `ohlc`array would be highlighted in the chart. To do this I set the `value` of the plotLine to `100`. Am I doing it wrong?

I really appreciate your help.

```
// ASSUME WE HAVE 300 BARS

const symbol = 'APPL';

const volume = [ ... ];
const ohlc = [ ... ];


Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {

    cropThreshold: 500,

    xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red',
            dashStyle: 'longdashdot',
            value: 100,
            width: 1,
            zIndex: 5
        }],
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        id: `${symbol}-ohlc`,
        name: `${symbol} OHLC`,
        data: ohlc,
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        id: `${symbol}-volume`,
        name: `${symbol} Volume`,
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that your `xAxis type is set as datetime`, so 100 value is just a few seconds after 1 Jan 1970. To make it work you need to set a date value that fits to the chart range.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1gwvcy9L/

Comment: I see. Let me try! Thank you very much!